# Pass Component as background image styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I Have 2 active buttons and onClick I would like to be able to display my svg component when the button state is active,

so I have 2 problems, If I attempt to pass in my svg component as a background prop then I get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string'

Also I need to render it only if active is true, I'm not sure how I can pass this as a prop here?

How can I conditionally render my svg component?

https://codesandbox.io/s/nn807p6k8j

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./icons.css";
import { TickOrange } from "./icons";

const Circle = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  &:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    background: #ff00ff;
  }
  ${({ active }) =>
    active &&
    `
    url(${props => props.background});
    border: 2px solid black;
  `};
`;

export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      active: false
    };
  }

  handleShowActive = () => {
    this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Circle
          active={this.state.active}
          background={<TickOrange />}
          onClick={this.handleShowActive && <TickOrange />}
        />
        <Circle active={this.state.active} onClick={this.handleShowActive} />
        <TickOrange />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**icons.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export const TickOrange = () => (
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
    <circle className="tickOrangeSt0" cx="11" cy="11" r="10" />
    <polyline className="tickOrangeSt1" points="4.8,11 9.9,15.5 16.9,6.8 " />
  </svg>
);
```

**icons.css**

```
.tickOrangeSt0 {
  fill: #ee9157;
}
.tickOrangeSt1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

Comment: what you tried in this line onClick={this.handleShowActive && <TickOrange />} ? show TickOrange in that handleShowActive function itself

Comment: I don't want to put it in the function itself as I will have multiple SVG objects that I will need to pass , is there another way?

Comment: Do you want to display the svg inside the <div>, or replace it ?